# When using subprocess.Popen(), stderr and stdout have no output

Tags: python, svn, subprocess

I'm using Python to automate an SVN commit, and I want to write the SVN command's output to a log file. The code that I have can make SVN run, but the problem is that on a successful commit, the `subprocess` invocation does not return any output for my log.

When I run SVN manually, by comparison, I get output that shows the progress of the command and shows which files are being committed. That's what I want in my log file. Is SVN outputting that data to a buffer than stdout or stderr? How can I capture that data for my log?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
cmd = "svn commit --non-interactive --no-auth-cache -m 'Automatic commit' ./"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                           shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           universal_newlines=True)
result = process.wait()

# Output
out = process.stdout.read()
err = process.stderr.read()
```

When I run this code and the commit is successful, the `out` and `err` variables are both empty.

Comment: How do you send the login credentials to do that? I'm trying the same and couldn't figure out how to send username and password for the same

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `wait()` when you are using PIPE. Use communicate()

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
          stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

out, err = process.communicate()
```

From the [subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> Warning
>   Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Comment: How does this answer the question, though? The question isn't about a deadlock

Comment: @Neowizard when I wrote this answer 9 years ago I must have focused on the part about the command writing out progress and the fact that the wait was not draining the buffers and could have caused a deadlock. I likely missed the detail where the OP said the wait unblocks and then there is nothing returned from the stdout or stderr pipes

Answer (score 0):

It's working in my solution:

```
svn_commit_t = 'svn commit "%s" -m "ticket #%s automerge"' % (directory, tic)

svn_co = subprocess.Popen(svn_commit_t, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

out, err = svn_co.communicate()
```